# Error 404 (not found) datatable select and button extention

Tags: html, datatables-1.10

I have loaded JS and CSS file for [datatable editor](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/simple/simple.html).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>QA</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1">
<link href="jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="DataTables-1.10.12/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<link href="DataTables-1.10.12/extentions/Buttons/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<link href="DataTables-1.10.12/extentions/Select/css/select.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<link href="datatable_editor/css/editor.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery-validate/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="DataTables-1.10.12/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="DataTables-1.10.12/extentions/Buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="DataTables-1.10.12/extentions/Select/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="datatable_editor/js/dataTables.editor.min.js"></script>
```

Then show error on Chromium developer tool, like :

```
GET http://..../DataTables-1.10.12/extentions/Select/js/dataTables.select.min.js 404 (Not Found)
```

the file location is same as i called the file in script.why?

Comment: Did you misspell "extensions" as "extentions" in your source code?

Comment: @Siguza please post as an answer, you have solved my problem.

Comment: In that case, the question should be closed as "a problem that can no longer be reproduced **or a simple typographical error**." :)

Comment: @Siguza its about two days i try to find the error..but i don't concern to spelling.lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**

Just replace directory name :

```
extentions
```

into

```
extensions
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the file structure. Or may be somewhere while calling the Js file you are calling wrongly. Give full code or where you are calling the JS.

Another option may be clear cache and try again as sometimes css & js files are stored in cache which doesn't reflect changes sometimes.